# expo-camera powers camera on immediately after asking for permission

Tags: expo, expo-camera

When asking for camera permission using `Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()` in the web app version, after granting permission, the camera is powered on immediately. In native apps, it does not happen. The effect is the same in Chrome, Safari, and in Mac, iOS. Can I somehow configure or workaround this? I want to grant permission for the camera, but the camera should not power up immediately.

I found no answer in the official Expo docs.

Reproduced here:

https://snack.expo.dev/@molnarzs_cardo/smelly-indigo-pastry